# Запись значения из textarea в txt файлы

Tags: php, ajax, textarea

Здравствуйте. У меня есть на странице 3 поля `textarea`. Как мне сделать, что бы при нажатии на кнопку их значения перезаписывали содержимое в разных `txt` файлах.
 Т.е. значение, к примеру, из поля `groups` вносилось в `groups.txt`, из `photo` в `photo.txt` и т.д.

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: В смысле? Вы хотите вносить информацию с `textarea` в какой-то файл или создавать `txt` файл с содержимым из `textarea`?

Comment: @Yuri , Я на одной странице изменяю разом 4 textarea, мне нужно чтобы каждая из них,вносила инфу в свой файл

Comment: http://prntscr.com/dpg2yn вот так как-то выглядит сейчас это дело.
Нужно все поля сохранить в разные txt со своими именами

Comment: Так вам нужно создавать txt файлы с их значениями или добавлять в уже существующие?

Comment: У меня есть уже 3 файла txt,в них нужно перезаписывать значения из полей.

Comment: Есть файл groups.txt,photo.txt и message.txt вот нужно в них,писать значения из полей "Группа","Фото","Текст" в каждый txt свое значение из своего поля)Надеюсь понятно выразил мысль)

Comment: Nasdomlan Urban3p, через `javascript`, через `ajax` отправляйте запрос со значениями этих полей на `php` страницу, где она будет менять содержимое этих файлов

Comment: Хмм,а не подскажите ,в какую сторону хоть копать?)А то знаний особенно в `ajax` в обще ноль)

Comment: Сейчас напишу ответ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Получаете значения из этих полей и отправляете их в ajax запросом:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "get",
   url: "PHPFile.php", // Название PHP файла
   dataType: "json",
   data: {'groups': $('#groups').val(), 'photo': $('#photo').val(), 'message': $('#message').val()},
   success: function(data) { // Это можно убрать, если не хотите получать ответа. data - это тело ответа на запрос
      alert('Запрос успешно отправлен! :)')
   },
   error: function(data) { // Это можно убрать, если не хотите получать сообщение о том, что вылезла ошибка. data - это тело ошибки
      alert('Какая-то ошибка :(')
   }
});
```

2) Получаете эти значения в *PHP* файле и перезаписываете файлы *txt*:

```
<?php
   header("Content-type:application/json; charset=utf-8");
   // Проверяем, все ли значения есть
   if(isset($_GET['groups']) && isset($_GET['photo']) && isset($_GET['message'])){
      // Если указаны все, то записываем значения в файлы
      file_put_contents('groups.txt', filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'groups', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));
      file_put_contents('photo.txt', filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'photo', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));
      file_put_contents('message.txt', filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'message', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));
   };
?>
```

Comment: Спасибо больше)буду теперь пытаться это все собрать в кучку,чтобы работало)

Comment: @NasdomlanUrban3p, попытайтесь )

Comment: Как то пока туго)ибо у меня 3 разных php страницы с таким содержанием

Comment: `<?php 
if ($_POST['content']) 
{ 
$file=fopen('groups.txt','w'); 
fputs($file,$_POST['content']); 
fclose($file); 
echo 'Данные записаны в файл!'; 
} 
else
{ 
echo ' 
<form method="post" action="script.php">
Список групп,оформляем по форме группа1,группа2, и т.д <br>
<textarea rows="5" cols="100" name="content"> 
'.file_get_contents('groups.txt').'
</textarea>
<input type="submit" value="Сохранить"> 
</form>'; 
}?>`

Comment: @NasdomlanUrban3p, это что? )

Comment: это я настолько убого и криво вношу данные в txt)Только начал просто это все осваивать)

Comment: @NasdomlanUrban3p, учитесь )

Comment: пытаюсь вот)по этому и задаю вопросы)Но пока увы мои "запросы" превышают мои знания)

Comment: @NasdomlanUrban3p, на самом деле всё это есть в интернете. Главное знать, как искать

Comment: это верно)Вот второй день мучаю запросы жанра "Запись данных в разные txt,Запись textarea в txt" и все в таком жанре)
В итоге тут решил вопрос задать)

Comment: @NasdomlanUrban3p, тут не с охотой отвечают на такое. В следующий раз ищите: отправка значений ajax, запись текста в файл и т.д.

Comment: просто беда для меня в том,что никому походу не приходило в голову чтобы через один файл сохранять 4 разных txt)
Может мою задачу и иначе можно решить,ибо эти txt я использую в скрипте для ВК Api чтобы постить записи в свои группы)
Но как иначе,кроме как через txt или mysql работать,идей нет)

Comment: @NasdomlanUrban3p, я в VK API не силён. Никогда не приходилось встречаться

Comment: а мне вот увы лишь вокруг него все вертится)
Решил попробовать переделать не через txt а через mysql)
Теперь  будет новая беда)как из тех же полей вносить данные в разные столбики mysql)Пошел читать)Спасибо вам огромное за помощь)

Comment: @NasdomlanUrban3p, обращайтесь :)

Comment: в итоге теперь застрял на сборке всего этого)Ибо теперь не могу понять как в итоге это объеденить с HTML формой и все собрать)Видимо рано мне в это)